# How to resume a video after calling SurfaceViewRenderer.pauseVideo() In webrtc org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer

Tags: android, webrtc, surfaceview

I'm successfully able to pause the video by calling

```
surfaceViewRenderer.pauseVideo();
```

But I'm not able to resume it. Any help will be useful. There's no function as start or resume.

Answer (score 4):

Even though Singh solution works, but you should know the framerate,

you should use `disableFpsReduction`.

```
surfaceViewRenderer.disableFpsReduction();
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally after a while I saw the code for the `surfaceViewRenderer.pauseVideo();` and what it does is set the fps to 0, so in order to resume the video we can just call

```
surfaceViewRenderer.setFpsReduction(30);
```

Where 30 is the fps (Frames Per Second) sent to the remote user.